# mysql assign auto number to non-primary key column

Tags: sql, mysql, duplicates

i have a table with columns

1. cid (customer id)
2. cemail (customer email)
3. cfax (customer email)
4. cname (customer name)

now i want that there should be no duplication in cid,cemail,cfax as i do that i make these all as primary keys but if only one value is different database accept data i want that it should check all values what should i do now ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `cid` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cemail` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  `cfax` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  `cname` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cemail` (`cemail`,`cfax`,`cname`)
);
```

Comment: i use this code but it also allow duplication of cfax and also cemail means that it does solve the problem

Comment: CREATE TABLE `customers` (
  `cid` int NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `cemail` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  `cfax` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  `cname` varchar(123) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`cid`),
  UNIQUE KEY `cemail` (`cemail`), UNIQUE KEY 'cfax' ('cfax'), UNIQUE KEY 'cname' ('cname')
);

it means define unique key for every column we want

Comment: this code work perfect CREATE TABLE customers ( cid int NOT NULL auto_increment, cemail varchar(123) NOT NULL, cfax varchar(123) NOT NULL, cname varchar(123) NOT NULL, PRIMARY KEY (cid), UNIQUE KEY cemail (cemail), UNIQUE KEY 'cfax' ('cfax'), UNIQUE KEY 'cname' ('cname') ); it means define unique key for every column we want

Answer (score 1):

You should create a [unique index](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-index.html) across those fields.

Just as a simple example (not tested):

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX my_index ON my_table(cemail, cfax, cname);
```